# Moving an arbitrary setting to a toolbar in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, ide-customization

I want to be able to modify a certain setting of Visual Studio right from the toolbar. 
Specifically, the number of parallel builds (Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run | maximum number of parallel project builds).
It can be either an edit box right on the toolbar or two buttons setting it to certain values.

I use Visual Studio 2005.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Write macros which will modify the two settings, then put macro on toolbar using "Cusomtize"

Comment: But how do I write the macro? Where do I find commands to modify settings?

Answer (score 0):

(almost) any VS command or property has a corresponding scriptable object that you can call in macros.

Do Alt-F11, go into the macro editor, open the object model window and start sniffing around. You can use search to look for the relevant class/function for a given property (e.g. the number of builds). Once you find it, it's just a matter of writing a few VBA lines that change it and, as [Ilya suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446080/moving-an-arbitrary-setting-to-a-toolbar-in-visual-studio/446102#446102), put that macro in your toolbar.

Btw, it should be possible to put an edit box in the toolbar to get the value; but it would probably be much easier just to call InputBox or something to ask the user for the input.